# StringCases is Confused with Patterns in Version 10.0.1

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, syntax-highlighting

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I observed the following with `StringCases` when trying to use rules/patterns. Here is a screenshot of the behavior:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Not only is the pattern highlighted in red, hovering the mouse over it claims it's an unknown option as shown above. Can anyone confirm this behavior? I'm on **Windows 8.1**. Regardless of this behavior, it does appear to work as expected.

Comment: Red color also under Linux. I don't have the hint. Maybe because I disabled some annoying hinting features in options.

Comment: @ybeltukov. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: It's even red in the help. So maybe it is on purpose? If you do not want to see red things, just do `StringCases["item13", {"item"~~x:DigitCharacter.. :> x}]`

Comment: @RolfMertig, why would it be on purpose, when it has worked that way forever and there's no documentation of a change in behavior?

Comment: I can also confirm (Win 8.1). On top of that, if I try an example (pick one at random, showing red) from the Documentation for StringCases in a clean NB, then hover my mouse over some the other red hints on the Documentation page, version 10.0.1 crashes. Seems related to hovering over more than 1 or 2 of the red hints. Very weird. Anyone else see this happen?

Comment: @RunnyKine Ijust cannot imagine that nobody at Wolfram saw this. Or do you think they do not read and check their own documentation?

Comment: In Win7 it is marked too.

Comment: @RolfMertig When you eliminate the impossible, what remains, however improbable, is the truth.

Comment: @IgorRivin They see, but do not observe. The distinction is clear.

Comment: Same on OSX 10.9.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax coloring bug was fixed in Mathematica 10.0.2:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  In which version did this bug first appear?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard A belated response, but it first appeared in 10.1.0 (together with the operator form of `StringCases`).